# ReSharper - format generic type constraint

Tags: c#, resharper, code-formatting

Here is an example of a generic type constraint declaration from [this MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(whereconstraint_CSharpKeyword);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue):

```
class MyClass<T, U>
    where T : class
    where U : struct
{ }
```

Is it possible to format my class using ReSharper in this  way? Currently after formatting runs the declaration resides on one line:

```
class MyClass<T, U> where T : class where U : struct
{ }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for `type constraints` in the ReSharper options. Un-ticking the `Allow type contsraints on the same line` should keep the formatting as you want it.

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks I really don’t know how I’ve missed that.